# How to avoid "unreachable statement" and "else without if" in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, unreachable-statement

So my code is meant to compare the y co-ordinate of the robot with the y co-ordinate of the target. I'm having problems making the function return anything when I add the print statements in. I have a feeling this has something to do with brackets, but I'm not exactly sure how to use them.

This is not the entire program, but it's the only bit with errors in it.

When I try to compile this:

```
public class Ex12 
{

    private byte isTargetNorth(IRobot robot)
    {

        if (robot.getLocationY() > robot.getTargetLocation().y) {

            return 1; System.out.println("north");

        } else if (robot.getLocationY() == robot.getTargetLocation().y) {

            return 0; System.out.println("no");

        } else { 

            return -1; System.out.println("south");

        }  

    }
}
```

I get error: unreachable statement

When I try this:

```
public class Ex12 
{

    private byte isTargetNorth(IRobot robot)
    {

        if (robot.getLocationY() > robot.getTargetLocation().y)

            return 1; System.out.println("north");

        else if (robot.getLocationY() == robot.getTargetLocation().y)

            return 0; System.out.println("no");

        else

            return -1; System.out.println("south");

    }
}
```

I get error: 'else' without 'if'

I get no errors when I remove the System.out.println() functions.

Comment: Apart from the obvious issue, a method with name `isTargetNorth` should really return a value of type `boolean`, and not `byte`.

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand?

Comment: @RohitJain: That's really far from the worst thing wrong here though, isn't it?

Comment: print the message before you return, you can't do something after you return (without using try/finally)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes. The real issue has already been answered. :)

Comment: Coding style suggestion: Never continue on the same line after a ;. That might obscure the program flow.

Answer (score 3):

The return statements exit your method.  So, the System.out's will never be called.

Answer (score 1):

The first one: Move the return statements after their respective `System.out.println` calls - return exits the current method, so `System.out.println` never gets called and is thus unreachable.

The second one is a case of confusing formatting: your code

```
if (robot.getLocationY() > robot.getTargetLocation().y)
    return 1; System.out.println("north");
else if ...
//...
```

Is actually equivalent to

```
if (robot.getLocationY() > robot.getTargetLocation().y) {
    return 1;
}
System.out.println("north");
else if ... //else without if right here, because else should follow immediately after an if block!
```

The else without if example is a good reminder of why you should be extra careful when omitting braces.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code block you have System.out.println after the return statement which makes them unreachable. If you put System.out.println in front of the return statements it'll work.

In your second example your removed the bocks ({...}) from the if statements which means you can only have exactly one statement per condition. You have two return and System.out.println.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
return 1;
System.out.println(""); // << This is written after you return to the calling method.
```

This means, you cannot write code here.

In the other code you wrote

```
if() Some Code;
// This statement will be executed, because  it is outside of the if-block
else 
    // The else above has no if.
```

To solve your problems:

1. Never write code after you return the return value.
2. Write parenthesis `{}` Mor to write, but you can always see the blocks.